# The code that freezes IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, internet-explorer-8

I have a facebook tab app that height changes page by page, so I wrote a 'snap' code that 
changes footer's position to absolute or static, but whenever I visit page with IE8 at that time freezes IExplorer.

At first I thought $(document).height() makes the page freezes but appearantly it is not. So any suggestion is appreciated.

```
var height = $(this).height(),
    width  = $(this).width();

$( window ).resize(function() {
    fsnap();
});

$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    if($(this).height() != height || $(this).width() != width) {
        fsnap();
    }
});


function getDocHeight() {
var D = document;
return Math.max(
    D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight,
    D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight,
    D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight
);
}

function fsnap(){
var dH;
if (navigator.appName != 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
    dH = $(document).height();
}else{
    dH = getDocHeight();
}

if(dH>$(".main").height()) $(".footer").addClass("footersnap");
else $(".footer").removeClass("footersnap");

if(dH > $(".footer").offset().top + $(".footer").height())
    $(".footer").removeClass("footersnap");
}
```

Comment: Could be the total lack of support for mutation events, and the fact that they are now officially deprecated, without ever even being really supported ?

Comment: you may be right but mutation part working I suppose, because whenever I remove inside of fsnap function, that won't freezes IE but I think there is something wrong with fsnap code, not so sure of course.

Comment: at the beginning of js file,
var height = $(this).height(), width  = $(this).width();

Comment: went to edit my previous comment and accidentally deleted it.  looks like the addClass() / removeClass() are triggering DOMSubtreeModified. since you are checking the current height against the original height of the screen you get into an infinite loop calling fsnap and triggering DOMSubtreeModified.

Comment: Oh thank you Nathan, that is correct. I've figured out I should just check the browser for DOMSubtreeModified part. Thanks.